# mysterious http-get-request from IE 11

Tags: html, http, internet-explorer, explorer

Currently, in our service, we open web browser to show the list of the notices to players when they start client at first. and the weird problem is that IE 11 browsers keep sending mysterious http-get-request.

The reason of why I use "Mysterious" word on the title, because the client code is using http-post-request! so we tried to count how many clients request to open web-url, and how many times server received request from clients. and there is no missing request from client's browser.

According to our access logs of tomcat server, it is http-get-request instead of post-method. and another mysterious point is the uri is cut as 255 characters length. and value of user-agent in the request header is like below.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

All of the mysterious request is "rv11.0", so I guess IE 11 is the criminal to make fake get-request. Does IE 11 request website in background to collect visit-history and user data???

Comment: Did you run IE11 with a proxy and see what the calls are?

Comment: omg, awesome! How do you know that?! I searched about this. and I found a long article about this. did you have similar experience about this?

https://rtfm.co.ua/en/http-redirects-post-and-get-requests-and-lost-data/

Comment: but, the most weird point is this. if the load balancer changed post-request to get-request sometimes, It could had been made data loss. but it couldn't. we using a load balancer of Google Cloud Platform. did they make post-request again when they got the problem which post-request changed as get-request.

Comment: I suggest you use the Network tab of the developer tools and check whether any get request sent while you perform an action on that site. Further, try to use a tool like Fiddler and check the requests. It may help narrow down the issue.